# is VFPV3 necessary (or suitable) for ARM64?

Tags: opencv, floating-point, arm, armv8

I am trying to compile OpenCV for the Jetson AGX Xavier (ARM64) with the option VFPV3 and get the error

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimization.cmake:527 (message)
Required baseline optimization is not supported: VFPV3
(CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE=;VFPV3;NEON)
```

Then reading several posts on the internet, it seems that VFPV3 is used for ARMv7. So my question is , is VFPV3 supported or even necessary to set active in a ARMv8 platform?

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of your previous one, [does ARMv8 come with NEON and VFPV3 built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412826/does-armv8-come-with-neon-and-vfpv3-built-in/67419649#67419649). Any reasons why you decided not to comment at all on the previous question/answer set, instead of keeping asking the same question in a slightly different form?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this entry](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17429) on the opencv github, using `-march=native -mcpu=native -mtune=native` is sufficient for opencv to be optimized for using NEON and VFPv3/VFPv4 when compiled with aarch64-linux-gcc.

More specifically [opencv/cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a5fdcf9881176ce756b601ee4b926586a88a42fe/cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake#L326-L345) does not use any specific option for AARCH64, since, again, NEON and VFP are implicitly present in an any standard armv8-a implementation - see `if(NOT AARCH64)` statement:

```
elseif(ARM OR AARCH64) 
   ocv_update(CPU_NEON_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_neon.cpp") 
   ocv_update(CPU_FP16_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp") 
   if(NOT AARCH64) 
     ocv_update(CPU_KNOWN_OPTIMIZATIONS "VFPV3;NEON;FP16") 
     if(NOT MSVC) 
       ocv_update(CPU_VFPV3_FLAGS_ON "-mfpu=vfpv3") 
       ocv_update(CPU_NEON_FLAGS_ON "-mfpu=neon") 
       ocv_update(CPU_NEON_FLAGS_CONFLICT "-mfpu=[^ ]*") 
       ocv_update(CPU_FP16_FLAGS_ON "-mfpu=neon-fp16 -mfp16-format=ieee") 
       ocv_update(CPU_FP16_FLAGS_CONFLICT "-mfpu=[^ ]*") 
     endif() 
     ocv_update(CPU_FP16_IMPLIES "NEON") 
   else() 
     ocv_update(CPU_KNOWN_OPTIMIZATIONS "NEON;FP16") 
     ocv_update(CPU_NEON_FLAGS_ON "") 
     ocv_update(CPU_FP16_IMPLIES "NEON") 
     set(CPU_BASELINE "NEON;FP16" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE}") 
   endif() 
 elseif(MIPS)
```

So, [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412826/does-armv8-come-with-neon-and-vfpv3-built-in/67419649#67419649), answer to `is VFPV3 supported in a ARMv8 platform` would be yes, and to `is it even necessary to set VFPV3 active in a ARMv8 platform?` would be no.

Comment: In the case this answer would not help, some kind of interactivity on why and how it could be improved would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will read it slowly, comment if I have any questions and mark it solved.